# Why don't custom colour settings in LXAppearance affect all applications?

Tags: themes, lubuntu, colors

In Lubuntu 12.04 I have created a customised colour scheme (using LXAppearance) which uses orange for selected items instead of blue.  Many applications don't appear to use the custom colour scheme however.

For example, in the system tray, xfce4-power-manager uses blue to highlight its menu selections while Network Manager uses orange.  PCManFM uses orange to highlight selected files in the main window but blue in its menus.

Is there any way to apply custom colour themes consistently?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **no**

Because, as you noticed, not all apps respect/use the system theme. This is not only about colors: other aspect of themes, like window decorators, are not used by all apps.

For example, take Chromium Browser, the free version of Chome. Notice how it's window borders and title bar are completely different from other apps. Chromium uses its own, custom widgets for its UI, and it's completely unaware of system theme.

So perhaps you're experiencing a similar issue with your apps. And unfortunately you cannot avoid id. But you can fill a bug report asking the developers to try to follow the system theme, if possible.